# Neighborhood cat wailing drooling and not eating

Tags: cats

We have a cat in our neighborhood. It was quite healthy and aggressive. However from past few days it had become too silent and avoided food. 2 days it disappeared just like that and then it came back with drooling mouth with saliva covering all her face and attaching all dust to it. It smells bad and its legs too are watery and dirty. It isn't trying to clean itself. It is avoiding every possible food given. Meat its trying to chew but shivering. A feral cat so unable to pick it up near vet. Its wailing every minute and growing weaker. What can I do best to help it in its last stages.

Comment: This sounds like the cat very urgently needs medical attention. The only real way to help would be to attempt to trap it, and bring it to a vet. If it is already very weak, sturdy gloves and two or three sweaters should be enough protection to pick it up if trapping isn't possible.

Comment: this sounds like the cat have been poisoned or maybe been hit by a car,no matter what it is it is serious and you need to take the cat to a vet as soon as possible.

Comment: Doesnt seem poisoning as its still making it. In line with vet now. Took a lot to catch it but thankfully its with me now. Will update next.

Comment: @MueezSiraj As Boba Fit mentions in their answer, rabies might be a possibility, if there is even a remote chance you might have been scratched, no matter how lightly, in fact if you are not 110% sure you have not been scratched, you absolutely need to get a rabies shot right away, especially if rabies is not considered eradicated in your country. Even if it is, the disease is 100% fatal to humans, so it is always advised to get the shot if scratched by wild animals.

Comment: Thank you so much for the concern. I've been scratched recently, I'll get the rabies shot tomo first thing.

Answer (score 7):

The drooling is quite worrisome. I don't want to say [rabies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8mBXtYFO9Y), but I must. The drooling is one of the tell-tale symptoms. Affected animals tend not to be able to swallow. There are several strains of rabies, each with slightly different symptoms. Some make the animal incredibly aggressive. Some just cause it to be disoriented and act unpredictably.

**DO NOT GET BITTEN OR SCRATCHED!**

The disease is spread by saliva through bites or scratches. Don't let other people, nor your pets, near this animal until you have had it checked out by a properly trained person.

I would urge you to call the local animal control authorities. They will have superior equipment and training. If there is no specific such program near you, then call the police and ask for guidance.

Comment: Thanks so much for such detailed response. I'll get the rabies shot tomo.

Comment: If you have been bitten or scratched by an animal you suspect could be rabid, go directly to an emergency medical center. Go FAST. A half hour could make a difference to your health.  You should only stop long enough to warn nearby people of the potential rabid animal. DO NOT WAIT until tomorrow. If you can safely use your cell phone on the way you can call the police or animal control folks.

Comment: Hi Boba, if got myself the shot and the animal is in safe house. I didnt know that neighborhood cats too can be fatal. Thanks for enlightening

Comment: I soo miss the cat now and still wondering how a playful kitty turned out to be carrying such virus within no time